# Reasons to use generic List over List of object

Tags: java, generics, abstraction

I know two reason to use generic List over List of objects.

1. To restrict what type of objects can be inserted into the List

   ```
   List<Object> stringObjects = Arrays.asList("a",new Integer(5));
   List<String> genericStrings = Arrays.asList("a",new Integer(5));//compile error
   ```
2. To have access to the correct method in your IDE

   ```
   List<Object> stringObjects = Arrays.asList("a",new Integer(5));
   List<String> genericStrings = Arrays.asList("a");
   stringObjects.get(0).length();//compile error
   genericStrings.get(0).length();
   ```

When I gave this answer to an interview, but they didn't seem very happy with my answer.
 So are there any other reason to user Generic List over List of objects?

Comment: Your title and final sentence aren't consistent. Which are you asking about?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question

Comment: Biggest two I can think of are non-reifiable generics and covariance of arrays. Then there are things like being able to create immutable lists, synchronize access etc. It's covered pretty comprehensively in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 25 "Prefer lists to arrays".

Comment: As an interviewer, I would followed up on your answer by asking why your first example is any different from `Object[] stringObjects = {"a", 5}; String[] genericStrings = {"a", 5};` in terms of compile-time safety, and similarly for your second example.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main reasons:

1. Stronger type checks at compile time.
2. Elimination of casts.

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what you had in mind was correct, but no well formated.

It's not about "having access to the correct method in your IDE", it is about polymorphism and avoiding explicit cast.

```
public interface DoAble {
    void doSomething();
}

public Class FirstImpl implements DoAble {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Do something here
    }
}

public Class SecondImpl implements DoAble {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

#### Usage with a List of Object

```
List list = new Arrays.asList(new SecondImpl(), new FirstImple());
for (Object o : list) {
    ((DoAble) o).doSomething();
}
```

It works, but it's ugly.

- Since whatever can be inserted in the list, it can throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException` at any time.
- We need to do an explicit cast, which we should always try to avoid.

#### Usage with Generic List

```
List<DoAble> list = new Arrays.asList(new SecondImpl(), new FirstImple());
for (DoAble o : list) {
    o.doSomething();
}
```

Easier to use and to read.

- No explicit casts.
- We are 100% that our list only contains objects that implements `DoAble`.

Comment: didn't you forget to implement the `DoAble` interface on the both `...Impl`-Types?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger yep, totally, i fixed it. Thanks